# How to connect to Postgres database from my local client that located inside google VM instance

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, tableau-api

I installed [Tableu server](https://www.tableau.com/) inside google VM instance. Server is connecting to Postgres database that is working on same server inside Virtual Machine. I'm trying to connect to this database from my local client by follow this [guide](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/perf_collect_server_repo.htm) . I created user, set permissions for this user.

My issue that I can't figure out how to specify `proxy setting` for VM instance to connect from my local client.

For example: for VM machine we are connecting with this command:

```
gcloud compute ssh --project=name_of_project --zone=us-central1-a name_of_virtual_machine
```

But I can’t figure out how to do this with Postgres connection string.

I tried to run https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy

```
 ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances={project_name}:us-central1:{name}=tcp:8060
```

Then connect with my local client with string:

`jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:8060/workgroup`

But connection is still blocked

Comment: Do you use Cloud SQL? I understood that not, it's a PostGres managed by yourselve on the VM. The proxy is to create a route (a proxy!!) between your VM and the Cloud SQL instance!

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I just tried all possible solutions. My attempt is to create ssh tunnel for google VM instance that will help me to connect to database that is working inside it

Comment: Why SSH? If you need to create a tunnul, create a iap-tunnel, and not a SSH connection! `gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel ....`

Comment: Then I can connect to database inside vm with `jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:8060/workgroup` ?

Comment: If you create the tunnel on the port 8060, yes you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to database in VM, first I did tunnel:

```
gcloud compute ssh server_name -- -N -L 8060:localhost:8060
```

And then connected to database via client with:

`jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:8060/mydbname`

Thanks @guillaume blaquiere for pointing me in right direction.